# Primes And Quadratic Residues

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

Below is the question:

Let $p$ be a prime. Prove there exists an integer $1\le x\le9$ such that $x$ and $x+1$ are quadratic residues mod $p$.

---

Please include a proof

Comment: you should do the proof. There are exactly sixteen cases, given by assuming $\pm 1$ values for each of the four Legendre symbols $(2|p),(3|p), (5|p), (7|p).$

Comment: One of the three pairs $(1, 2), (4, 5), (9, 10)$ would be OK.

Comment: I'm not your downvoter, but what you describe as "the question" is actually an imperative statement, "Prove there exists...".  You might get a more favorable response if you put your demand in some clearer context.  Why do you care?  What did you do that "tested it out"?

Comment: Isn't the statement false for $p<7$?

Comment: no. take x=p, and we are done for p<7

Comment: It is a somewhat unconventional to treat prime $p$ itself as a quadratic residue mod $p$.  Of course you are asking the Question, so ultimately you are the expert on what you intend.  However it would be helpful to future Readers if you clarified your problem statement to include that information in the body of the Question, not just as a Comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $2$ is a quadratic residue, then $1$ and $2$ are consecutive quadratic residues.

If $5$ is a quadratic residue, then $4$ and $5$ are consecutive quadratic residues.

But if $2$ and $5$ are not quadratic residues, then $9$ and $10$ are.

Comment: for p=17, 8 and 9 are quad residues. 5^2 and 3^2 respectively. therefore this solution doesn't work

Comment: @KarmaPenny:  for $p=17$, $2$ is a quadratic residue ($6^2$), so $1$ and $2$ are consecutive quadratic residues identified by this solution

Comment: okay. can you prove your result?

Comment: $1, 4, $ and $9$ are always quadratic residues, and the product of non-quadratic residues is a quadratic residue modulo a prime